# Residue class field of coordinate ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If $X$ is an irreducible affine curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, then its coordinate ring $O(X)$ is a Dedekind domain. Suppose $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime (hence maximal) ideal in $O(X)$ then $O(X)/\mathfrak{p}$ is a field. Is it isomorphic to $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is. This is the [Zariski Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma).

Comment: Thanks for the link which in turn points to A&M for a proof. The result that I want is actually Corollary 7.10

Answer (score 0):

$O(X)$ is a finitely generated algebra over $k$, so we can write $O(X) = k[\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n]$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, every maximal ideal $m$ will be of the form $m=(\xi_1 - a_1,\dots,\xi_n - a_n)$ with $a_i \in k$. From this it is seen that $O(X)/m = k[\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n] / (\xi_1 - a_1,\dots,\xi_n - a_n) \cong k$.

Comment: Not sure about this. Seems to be treating generators as variables.

Comment: Sorry about this comment. I just wanted to check that the numbers agree: If $X$ is a curve defined by $f(x,y)=0$ then I believe that $(O(X)$ is generated by $x + (f), y +(f)$ and maximal ideals are of the form $(x-a,y-b)$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, more precisely $(x-a,y-b)$ modulo $(f)$.